# jQuery replaceWith() - re-using the removed values

Tags: jquery, arrays, href, replacewith

I'm using jQuery to de-dupe identical links that are close together, for keyboard users. I still want mouse users to be able to click the 'more' link if they want, so I'm putting the link back on hover.

What I've done is working, but it seems like a bit of a palaver. I read in the [Jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/%20jQuery%20api) that replaceWith() returns the replaced values, but where's it keeping them? How can I get them back when needed?

I understood that the original values go into some sort of array. It looks like it should be possible to create a named array in the first function, then access its correct values in the second. I'm really bad with arrays & will welcome any assistance.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

// dedupe links in post list widgets

     $( ".widget li" ).each(function( i ) {
   var firstA = $(this).children( 'a:first-child' );
   var myH = $( firstA ).attr( 'href' );
   var dupeA = $( firstA ).siblings( 'a' );
   var dupeH = $( dupeA ).attr( 'href' );
   if( dupeH == myH ) { 
    $( dupeA ).replaceWith( '<span class="more-link">Open</span>' );
   }
    });
 
// replace link if needed

  $( '.widget li' ).hover(function( i ) {
   var myH = $(this).children( 'a:first-child' ).attr( 'href' );
   $(this).children( 'span.more-link' ).replaceWith( '<a href="' + myH + '" class="more-link">Open</a>' ).addClass( 'hover' );
  });
   
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li, li > * {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
li a:first-child ~ * {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.more-link {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="widget">
 <ul class="index-widget">
  <li>
   <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
   <time>14 May 2018</time>
   <span class="index-excerpt">Answers questions</span>
   <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="more-link">Open</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="https://jquery.com">jQuery</a> 
   <time>15 May 2018</time>
   <span class="index-excerpt">Prompts questions</span>
   <a href="https://jquery.com" class="more-link">Open</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Further edit: Code on here now. Thanks, zer00ne.

Comment: Please add HTML in a [mcve] by clicking the button with brackets: `<>` and placing your source there.

Comment: Done it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You're welcome. The second part is commented:`/// replace link if needed` how is that determined?

Comment: Mouse users don't mind repetitive links, so I wanted the link back on hover only.

Comment: I see. You may want to reassess your strategy. Answer these questions (not necessarily as a comment here but to yourself if you prefer):  Is **UX** (**u**ser e**x**perience) better with these extra links? Do the duplicate links serve a function that the original link cannot? Good UX has consistent behavior between interfaces (as close as possible) like binding keyboard events with mouse events. Here's an [article which addresses concerns that coincide with your particular question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets).

Comment: I got a brilliant answer from @muecas below. Now I've learned how to access stored values - and capture events, which I'll need for my next step. I'm familiar with the guidance you linked - thanks. I often use keyboard navigation myself and can't over-emphasise the unhelpfulness of most websites' front ends. Including mine, until I've fixed it.

To answer you directly: Yes, most people expect a choice of clicking above or below the excerpt. Tabbing through multiple links, however, is really bloody annoying! And "keyboard users deserve eye candy", hence the class on the span :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the returning value of the `replaceWith` function so you could reuse it later.

For example:

```
var replaced = $( dupeA ).replaceWith( '<span class="more-link">Open</span>' );
```

`replaced` will then be a reference to the replaced `dupeA` element. So later you could just simply do:

```
$(this).children( 'span.more-link' ).replaceWith( replaced );
```

to put `dopeA` back on.

You will be aware of the scope of the variables to be able of using `replaced` in the place you need it. In you example you would need to have `replaced` defined as a global variable or defined in the scope where both event functions are binded (main executed function).

More info about `replaceWith` function can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Hope it helps!

**Edit**
I've applied the function to your case, with minor improvements.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 $('.widget li').each(function(i, e) {
  var firstA = $(this).children('a:first-child');
  var myH = $(firstA).attr('href');
  var dupeA = $(firstA).siblings('a');
  var dupeH = $(dupeA).attr('href');
  var replaced = false; // Set a variable to check if the item has been replaced
  var repA; // Stored the replaced item
  if(dupeH == myH) {
      // Replaces the item and stores the item in a variable
   repA = $(dupeA).replaceWith($('<span class="more-link">Open [replaced]</span>'));
      // Only if replaced, the mouseneter event is set
   $(e).mouseenter(function() {
        // If the element has not been replaced yet
    if(replaced === false) {
     // Sets the element as replaced
          replaced = true;
          // Put back the replaced element
     $(this).children('span.more-link').replaceWith(repA.addClass('hover'));
    }
   });
  }
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li, li > * {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
li a:first-child ~ * {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
.more-link {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: .3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="widget">
 <ul class="index-widget">
  <li>
   <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
   <time>14 May 2018</time>
   <span class="index-excerpt">Answers questions</span>
   <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="more-link">Open</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="https://jquery.com">jQuery</a> 
   <time>15 May 2018</time>
   <span class="index-excerpt">Prompts questions</span>
   <a href="https://jquery.com" class="more-link">Open</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't. I must be out of my depth. The only way I can see of restoring the original values would be to put a 'for' loop in the function, storing each value as it's found. That feels more complicated than what we have! The way the api page is worded, it looks like some mystery 'replaced' store has been created. I thought I could use it to restore the values, rather than sending more code.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and i'll write a snippet on how to apply my example to your case.

Comment: @cherryaustin i've updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, this is great! I've just learned at least 2 new things. Cheers.